# How to use NULL in SELECT

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to use NULLs in my select statement like so:

```
select NULL,
       name,
       NULL
from   names
```

How do I code this in LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on Candie's answer, if you use an anonymous type, you'd need to specify the `null` property values:

```
class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var names = new List<Name>() { new Name() { FirstName = "Albert"}, 
                                        new Name() { FirstName = "Bob"}};

        var values = from n in names
                     select new
                     {
                         FirstVal = null as object,
                         SecondVal = n.FirstName,
                         ThirdVal = null as object
                     };
   }
}
```

You can't assign `null` to an anonymous type's property, so you have to cast it to `object`.

Comment: you don't have to cast null to object; you can cast to any other reference type or nullable value type.  Also, `(object)null` makes more sense than `null as object`.  I suppose the compiler would optimize away the `as` operation, but why put it there in the first place?

Comment: I wanted to cast to as base of an object as possible.  Using the `as` notation I knew would return `null`, so I went with that.  It's a little more clear (to me at least).  Either using the `as` or a direct cast probably compiles down to the same as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that,
I think I've found another way, but not tested:

```
select new
{
    firstVal = String.Empty,
    SecondVal = n.FirstName
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between string.Empty and null. Typically null means that the value isn't set whereas string.empty indicates that it was set to an empty value.